# How do I link two or more files?

Tags: c#

I got a question for ya'll. how do I link these two files?
I want the class in EmptyClass.cs to be usable in Program.cs.
Hope that makes sense I don't know how I could explain that differently.

[image]

Comment: Show us your code, and what you have tried to do this so far

Comment: this is the program.cs https://pastebin.com/G4TYnqCc and this is the EmptyClass.cs https://pastebin.com/JTMT3CRu

Comment: You don´t "link" files. Instead you *use* objects created at some point (not neccessarily another file, also another namespace or whatever) within another object. That´s what object-orientation is about. The principles here are about *objects*, not *source-files*. You should definitly read some basics about C# and OOP.

Comment: I'm still learning, and learning by other works best for me, I've tried reading about c# but didn't get most of what I read so I ask questions instead. If that's ok @HimBromBeere

Comment: Don´t paste your entire code-base. Only write the *relevant* code **directly into the question**. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those two classes share the same namespace, you can instantiate it (unless it's an abstract class) just like this:

```
EmptyClass foo = new EmptyClass();
```

If they aren't in the same namespace, you either need to add a `using` declaration for the namespace, or add a namespace before the class name:

```
using yourNamespace;
...
EmptyClass foo = new EmptyClass();
```

or

```
yourNamespace.EmptyClass foo = new yourNamespace.EmptyClass();
```